# No trivial case in std::lower_bound?

Tags: c++, algorithm, std, time-complexity, lower-bound

**Why is there no trivial comparison as first step in [std::lower_bound( )](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)?**

As initial step `std::lower_bound` changes iterator `it` from `first` in list to the center position:

```
step = std::distance(first,last) / 2;
it = std::advance(first, step);
```

After that the algorithm starts to compare that center-`it` with given `value`:

```
if (*it < value) { ... } else { ... }
```

But the trivial case would be to make one comparison as initial step before repositioning `it`:

```
if (value < *first) return last;
// else start original algorithm ...
```

Imagine there is a very long list and you still need to wait until the `std::lower_bound` in its current form realizes, that `value < *first` is true. Sure it is *O( log_2( last - first ) )*, but in such a case it could be *O(1)* with only one additional line.

Comment: The amortized time will be the same, as such situations are probably not very common. But cppreference is not the de-facto standard in how to implement the algorithm, I think the standard requires only some given complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way of implementing `lower_bound` allows you to do this trivial check, whereas otherwise you would always be forced to do this check. In the sense of "you don't pay for what you don't use" this makes sense to me.

Because `lower_bound` works on sorted structures only, you can always compare with the first element if you deem it worth it.

Still, the actual implementation looks different, so some STL-implementations may actually do this check.

The implementation from [SGI](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_algo.h) e.g. looks like this (check not done!):

```
template <class _ForwardIter, class _Tp, class _Distance>
_ForwardIter __lower_bound(_ForwardIter __first, _ForwardIter __last,
                           const _Tp& __val, _Distance*) 
{
  _Distance __len = 0;
  distance(__first, __last, __len);
  _Distance __half;
  _ForwardIter __middle;

  while (__len > 0) {
    __half = __len >> 1;
    __middle = __first;
    advance(__middle, __half);
    if (*__middle < __val) {
      __first = __middle;
      ++__first;
      __len = __len - __half - 1;
    }
    else
      __len = __half;
  }
  return __first;
}

template <class _ForwardIter, class _Tp>
inline _ForwardIter lower_bound(_ForwardIter __first, _ForwardIter __last,
                const _Tp& __val) {
  __STL_REQUIRES(_ForwardIter, _ForwardIterator);
  __STL_REQUIRES_SAME_TYPE(_Tp,
      typename iterator_traits<_ForwardIter>::value_type);
  __STL_REQUIRES(_Tp, _LessThanComparable);
  return __lower_bound(__first, __last, __val,
                       __DISTANCE_TYPE(__first));
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I take from it, that I as the dev should know if it is worth doing the trivial check first. If so, I can do it in my own code before the call to `std::lower_bound`. All other devs make the call expecting `value` is in the list.